# Why does Solve give a blank result?

Tags: equation-solving

```
m[t_] := -50 Sin[0.214068 (t - 35.1493)] + 50
Solve[-50 Sin[0.214068 (t - 35.1493)] + 50 == 100 && 
  0 <= t <= 365, t, Reals]
```

Out[288]= {}

Answer (score 6):

Make the numbers exact:

```
m[t_]:=-50 Sin[0.214068 (t-35.1493)]+50;
Solve[Rationalize[m[t]]==100&&0<=t<=365,t,Reals]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

`Solve` should really be used with exact numbers. Otherwise, use `NSolve`

```
 NSolve[m[t] == 100 && 0 <= t <= 365, t, Reals]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: `NSolve`  loses  some roots.

Answer (score 1):

The use of `Reduce` instead of `Solve` does the job.

```
Reduce[-50 *Sin[0.214068 *(t - 35.1493)] + 50 == 100 && 0 <= t <= 365, t, Reals] // Simplify
```

> `C[1] \[Element]  Integers && ((0 <= C[1] <= 11. &&  t == 27.8115 + 29.3514 C[1]) || (-1. <= C[1] <= 10. &&  t == 57.1628 + 29.3514 C[1]))`

The output shows that each root has multiplicity two. The `Reals` domain in the above may be omitted.